Lexical, custom node and transform
I have custom TextNode but AutoLinkPlugin doesn't work with it. After a bit of debugging  it looks like Transform doesn't respect nodes replacement.
I managed to get it working by copying key of TextNode when creating my custom node.
But documentation is a bit lacking on this so I don't know if this is a good idea.
So I wonder, should I copy key? Am I missing some setting that lets Transforms work with custom nodes? Or should I write custom AutoLinkPlugin?
Here are code samples:
// Custom Node 
// from https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/serialization#handling-extended-html-styling

import {
  $isTextNode,
  DOMConversion,
  DOMConversionMap,
  DOMConversionOutput,
  NodeKey,
  TextNode,
  SerializedTextNode,
  LexicalNode
} from 'lexical';

export class ExtendedTextNode extends TextNode {
  constructor(text: string, key?: NodeKey) {
    super(text, key);
  }

  static getType(): string {
    return 'extended-text';
  }

  static clone(node: ExtendedTextNode): ExtendedTextNode {
    return new ExtendedTextNode(node.__text, node.__key);
  }

  static importDOM(): DOMConversionMap | null {
    const importers = TextNode.importDOM();
    return {
      ...importers,
      code: () => ({
        conversion: patchStyleConversion(importers?.code),
        priority: 1
      }),
      em: () => ({
        conversion: patchStyleConversion(importers?.em),
        priority: 1
      }),
      span: () => ({
        conversion: patchStyleConversion(importers?.span),
        priority: 1
      }),
      strong: () => ({
        conversion: patchStyleConversion(importers?.strong),
        priority: 1
      }),
      sub: () => ({
        conversion: patchStyleConversion(importers?.sub),
        priority: 1
      }),
      sup: () => ({
        conversion: patchStyleConversion(importers?.sup),
        priority: 1
      }),
    };
  }

  static importJSON(serializedNode: SerializedTextNode): TextNode {
    return TextNode.importJSON(serializedNode);
  }

  isSimpleText() {
    return (
      (this.__type === 'text' || this.__type === 'extended-text') &&
      this.__mode === 0
    );
  }

  exportJSON(): SerializedTextNode {
    return {
      ...super.exportJSON(),
      type: 'extended-text',
      version: 1,
    }
  }
}

export function $createExtendedTextNode(text: string): ExtendedTextNode {
    return new ExtendedTextNode(text);
}

export function $isExtendedTextNode(node: LexicalNode | null | undefined): node is ExtendedTextNode {
    return node instanceof ExtendedTextNode;
}

function patchStyleConversion(
  originalDOMConverter?: (node: HTMLElement) => DOMConversion | null
): (node: HTMLElement) => DOMConversionOutput | null {
  return (node) => {
    const original = originalDOMConverter?.(node);
    if (!original) {
      return null;
    }
    const originalOutput = original.conversion(node);

    if (!originalOutput) {
      return originalOutput;
    }

    const backgroundColor = node.style.backgroundColor;
    const color = node.style.color;
    const fontFamily = node.style.fontFamily;
    const fontSize = node.style.fontSize;

    return {
      ...originalOutput,
      forChild: (lexicalNode, parent) => {
        const originalForChild = originalOutput?.forChild ?? ((x) => x);
        const result = originalForChild(lexicalNode, parent);
        if ($isTextNode(result)) {
          const style = [
            backgroundColor ? `background-color: ${backgroundColor}` : null,
            color ? `color: ${color}` : null,
            fontFamily ? `font-family: ${fontFamily}` : null,
            fontSize ? `font-size: ${fontSize}` : null,
          ]
            .filter((value) => value != null)
            .join('; ');
          if (style.length) {
            return result.setStyle(style);
          }
        }
        return result;
      }
    };
  };
}

// Editor init
export function EditorLexicalView({selectedFile} : Props) {
  const { ref: toolbarRef, height: toolbarHeight = 1 } = useResizeObserver<HTMLDivElement>({box:'border-box'}); 

  const initialConfig = {
    namespace: 'MyEditor',
    theme: EditorTheme,
    onError,
    nodes: [
      ExtendedTextNode,
      { replace: TextNode, with: (node: TextNode) => new ExtendedTextNode(node.__text, node.__key) },
      ListNode,
      ListItemNode,
      LinkNode,
      AutoLinkNode
    ]
  };
  const urlRegExp = new RegExp(
    /((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=+$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=+$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[+~%/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/,
 );
 function validateUrl(url: string): boolean {
    return url === 'https://' || urlRegExp.test(url);
 }

 const URL_REGEX =
 /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})/;

const EMAIL_REGEX =
 /(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))/;

const MATCHERS = [
 createLinkMatcherWithRegExp(URL_REGEX, (text) => {
    console.trace()
    return text;
 }),
 createLinkMatcherWithRegExp(EMAIL_REGEX, (text) => {
    return `mailto:${text}`;
 }),
];

  return (
    <LexicalComposer initialConfig={initialConfig}>
        <div className='editor-container'>
            <ToolbarPlugin ref={toolbarRef}/>
                    <div className='editor-inner' style={{height: `calc(100% - ${toolbarHeight}px)`}}>
                <RichTextPlugin
                contentEditable={<ContentEditable className="editor-input section-to-print" spellCheck={false}/>}
                placeholder={null}
                ErrorBoundary={LexicalErrorBoundary}
                />
                </div>
        </div>
        <TestPlugin selectedFile={selectedFile}/>
        <HistoryPlugin />
        <AutoFocusPlugin />
        <RegisterCustomCommands />
        <LinkPlugin validateUrl={validateUrl}/>
        <AutoLinkPlugin matchers={MATCHERS}/>
    </LexicalComposer>
  );
}


Ok, I have figure it out.
this:
{ replace: TextNode, with: (node: TextNode) => new ExtendedTextNode(node.__text, node.__key) },

also needs
, withKlass: ExtendedTextNode

